# Returning full text search results

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I am following this tutorial :

http://creative-punch.net/2013/12/implementing-laravel-4-full-text-search

I have followed it through adapting to my own project my question is how do I display the results that I have queried thanks

code as follows : view

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Laravel PHP Framework</title>
    <style>
      @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700);

      body {
        margin:0;
        font-family:'Lato', sans-serif;
        text-align:center;
        color: #999;
    }

    .welcome {
        width: 300px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin-left: -150px;
        margin-top: -100px;
    }

    a, a:visited {
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 32px;
        margin: 16px 0 0 0;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>


 <div class="search">
   {{ Form::model(null, array('route' => array('ec2_instance.search'))) }}
    {{ Form::text('query', null, array( 'placeholder' => 'Search query...' )) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Search') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}


 </div>




 </body>
 </html>
```

my controller :

```
 <?php 

 class PostsController extends BaseController {

public function postSearch(){
    $q = Input::get('query');

   $posts = ec2_instance::whereRaw("MATCH(instance_id,instance_type,availability_zone, status_checks,alarm_status, public_dns, key_name ) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", 
        array($q))->get();

    return View::make('ec2_instance.search', compact('ec2_instance'));

}
}
?>
```

my routes :

```
Route::get('/', function()
 {
  return View::make('search');
  });

 Route::post(
   'ec2_instance/search', 
      array(
    '   as' => 'ec2_instance.search', 
        'uses' => 'PostsController@postSearch'
   )
  );

 ?>
```

Comment: Please show us what you've got. We need to see your code (even if it's nearly the same as the tutorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'll make some assumptions here so you may have to alter the code a bit to fit your needs...

First you certainly don't need to pass `ec2_instance` to the view but rather the result `$posts`

```
return View::make('ec2_instance.search', compact('posts'));
```

Now since your result will be a collection of posts you need to loop over it in your view:

#### ec2_instance.search

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{-- display properties here --}}
    {{ $post->key_name }}
    {{-- etc... --}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: feedback much appreciated however I am still having issues largely due to being a complete newbie anyway in my view I want to display the results as per the foreach loop above now my $posts variable is located in my postscontroller class when I try and reference it it does not work ie '@foreach(PostsController::$posts as $post)' I know its to do with using keyword static but just cant seem to figure it out

Comment: To use a variable in the view you need to pass it. Which is what you do when using the second parameter in `View::make` like the code shows above. You can then just use it like `$posts` (also like shown above)

Comment: I agree that should work that being said I am getting 'Undefined variable: posts' in my view

Comment: And you're doing this: `return View::make('ec2_instance.search', compact('posts'));`?

Comment: yes exactly that I have that line in the controller and then in my view ec2_instance.blade.php I have the loop to elaborate I have 2 views one for get search.blade.php and returning to ec2_instance.blade.php

Comment: Can you try `View::share('posts', $posts);` before you return the view?

Comment: this is getting odder by the minute now I have 'Route [search] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\awsconfig\app\views\search.blade.php)' using routes as in question. if I set the post route to match the get route ie 'Route::post(
    '/', 
    array(
        'as' => 'search', 
        'uses' => 'PostsController@postSearch'' it works but obviously looping back on itself any ideas ?

Comment: Because your route is called `ec2_instance.search` for more help I'd need to see the `search` view...

Comment: search view is as in question ec2_instance view is as in question plus for loop in your previous answer if that makes sense thanks

Comment: You still got `array('route' => array('ec2_instance.search'))` or did you change that to `array('route' => array('search'))`?

Comment: had to change it to just search as otherwise I just get the aforementioned view not found

Comment: Man you gotta get your basics straight. The `route` when making a form refers to the route name (`as`). Also your view path/name is wrong. `ec2_instance.search` means it should be inside the folder `ec2_instance` so the path `ec2_instance/search.blade.php`. I recommend you read the [official docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2)